# An irrationality criterion of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

what I ask is a bit convoluted.
First, we will define a *relace*:

***Def**: Let $\;{q_1},{q_2}\dots,{q_n}\dots \;  ({q_i}\in\Bbb Q)$ such that $\beta=\sum_{i=1}^\infty q_i$. We say that a **relace** of the series is a new series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty p_j$ fulfilling:*

1. $p_j=\sum_{i\in I_j} q_i$,$\,$ *with* $\,$ $\Bbb N =\bigsqcup_{j\in\Bbb N} I_{j}\;$ *(disjoint union)*
2. $\beta=\sum_{j=1}^\infty p_j$

If the relace $\sum_{j=1}^\infty p_j$ is a geometric series, we say that it's a **geometric relace**.

***Example***: Let $M_e$ be the Mengoli series: $$M_e=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{42}+\frac{1}{56}+\frac{1}{72}+\dots$$ and we choose $I_k=\{2^{k-1},\dots,2^k-1\}$,$\;$ for $k=1,2,3,\dots$
Then $$M_e=(\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{12})+(\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{42}+\frac{1}{56})+(\frac{1}{72}+\dots=(\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{1}{4})+(\frac{1}{8})+\dots$$ which is a geometric series: $$M_e=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}=2^{-1}\frac{1}{1-2^{-1}}=1$$

I want to prove this theorem:

***Theorem***: Let $\beta=\sum_{i=1}^\infty q_i$ be a rational series (of rational terms). Then the following statements are equivalent:

1. $\beta$ *admits a geometric relace.*
2. $\beta\in\Bbb Q$

***Proof:***

1. $\Rightarrow$ 2) is evident, since every geometric series (of rational terms) converges to a rational number.
2. $\Rightarrow$ 1) ? (I don't even know where to start)

Thanks for trying it!

Comment: How do you know it's a theorem? Where have you seen this claim being made?

Comment: @GerryMyerson it's not a theorem, my apologies, this is a conjecture that I believe to be true.

Comment: Are the $I_j$ allowed to be infinite? Also I think there are trivial counter-examples if you don't require infinitely many of the $q_i$ to be non-zero.

Comment: My guess is that it's false. I'd start looking for counterexamples.

Comment: Here's where I'd look for a counterexample. $1/2+1/3+1/7+1/43+\dotsb=1$ where each term is of the form $1/a$ where $a$ is the smallest integer that keeps the sum below $1$. (So, for example, $1/2+1/3+1/6=1>1/2+1/3+1/7$, so the 3rd term is $1/7$.) The terms in this series go to zero very quickly, and I suspect there's no way to partition them to get numbers that only go to zero geometrically.

Comment: Making any progress, tomas?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was checking your example, and it does seem to be true. That is why I had the doubt of imposing another condition for this conjecture by defining:
 Let $\;{(q_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}} \subseteq \Bbb Q$ such that $\beta=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty q_i$. We say that a **reverse relace** of the series is a new series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty u_k$ fulfilling: 
1) $q_i=\displaystyle\sum_{j\in I_i} u_j$,$\,$ *with* $\,$
$\Bbb N =\bigsqcup_{i\in\Bbb N}
I_{i}\;$ *(disjoint union)*
2) $\beta=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty u_k$  \, and $u_k \in \Bbb Q,\, \forall k$

Comment: @GerryMyerson So the conjecture is: ***Conjecture:*** Let $\beta=\sum_{i=1}^\infty q_i$ be a rational series. Then the following statements are equivalent:

1) $\beta$ admits a relace and a reverse relace that result in a geometric series.
2) $\beta\in\Bbb Q$

Comment: To say the two statements are equivalent is to imply that a rational series with a rational sum admits a geometric relace, which my example says is false. I'm going to try to post a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are going to consider the series
$$
{1\over2}+{1\over3}+{1\over7}+{1\over43}+\dotsb=1
$$
where each denominator is one more than the product of all the previous denominators, e.g., $43=1+(2\times3\times7)$. Note also that
$$
1={1\over2}+{1\over2}={1\over2}+{1\over3}+{1\over6}={1\over2}+{1\over3}+{1\over7}+{1\over42}=\dotsb
$$
so each successive denominator is larger by $1$ than the denominator that would make the terms sum to $1$.

Now we are aiming for a geometric series with first term $a$ and common ratio $r$, and sum $1$, so
$$
a+ar+ar^2+\dotsb={a\over1-r}=1
$$
From this it follows that $r=1-a$.

Now in any geometric relace the first term will be the largest, so it must include the term $1/2$, since the series can't have two terms greater than or equal to one-half. So, $a\ge1/2$.

Then the second term, $ar=a(1-a)$, will be at most $1/4$, so neither it, nor any succeeding term, can include $1/3$. So $1/3$ must be in the first term, so $a\ge(1/2)+(1/3)=5/6$.

From $a\ge5/6$, we get for the second term $a(1-a)\le (5/6)(1/6)=5/36<1/7$, so $1/7$ can't be in the second (or any later) term, so it too must be in the first term. Thus, $a\ge(1/2)+(1/3)+(1/7)=41/42$.

Then $a\ge41/42$ implies the second term $a(1-a)\le(41/42)(1/42)<1/43$ (because $41\times43<42^2$), so $1/43$ must be in the first term. At this point, we should make this a proof by mathematical induction, but I think the argument is clear enough from the preceding calculations; every term in our series must be included in the first, and thus only, term of the alleged geometric relace, so there is no geometric relace.

Comment: Thanks for the help!